# Which country is INDIA in?

Tags: lateral-thinking, geography, knowledge

An intrepid globetrotter needs to know this:

BENIN is in Libya 
CANADA is in China 
DENMARK is in the United States 
FRANCE is in Germany 
INDIA is in ??

Comment: This is one of the most amusing puzzle questions I've ever Benin. I think I'll pop open a Canada soda I got at the store, Denmark the best answer with an upvote. I'll make sure to show all my France this question. India will be happy to know that I upvoted your question too.

Comment: I read the title of this question and was very very confused.

Comment: You have inspired me to create my own question: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30683/japan-is-in-india

Comment: I liked that puzzle - bravo!

Comment: At first I thought this would be related to the [Principle of Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), as in this (true) sentence: "If Benin is in Libya, then Benin is in China."

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The answer is:

> United States

Because:

> The first three letters are IATA codes of airports:
>
>  **BEN**in = [Benina International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benina_International_Airport) in Benghazi, Libya
>  **CAN**ada = [Guangzhou Baiyun International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guangzhou_Baiyun_International_Airport) in Guangzhou, China
>  **DEN**mark = [Denver International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denver_International_Airport) in Denver, United States
>  **FRA**nce = [Frankfurt Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt_Airport) in Frankfurt, Germany
>  **IND**ia = [Indianapolis International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indianapolis_International_Airport) in Indianapolis, United States

Comment: beat me to it! good answer

Comment: I liked that the puzzle was alphabetical, but I was sad it was missing some letters. Now that there's an answer, we can fill in the blanks! :) ALBANIA is in the United States, ESTONIA is in the United States, GHANA is in Algeria, HUNGARY is in Taiwan...

Comment: And HELL is in Finland...

Comment: @vurp0 and HEAVEN is in Afghanistan...

Answer (score 9):

Another answer could be

> INDIA    itself. :)

Based on the explanations for BENIN , CANADA , DENMARK and FRANCE given by [Bolo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9200/bolo).

> **IND**ia :: [**Ind**ira Gandhi **I**nternational **A**irport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indira_Gandhi_International_Airport) in Delhi, India

Comment: Except that IND is not a generally used abbreviation for that airport (it's DEL according to IATA), as stated in your own link.

Comment: Never mind "generally used", it's *never* referred to as IND or (INDIA) by anyone, let alone IATA. Nice try, though, Jonny789 :)