# Which country is Italy in?

Tags: knowledge, geography

Find a country Italy is in, given that:

> Belgium is in The Netherlands
>
> Germany is in Switzerland
>
> The United Arab Emirates are in Oman
>
> Russia is in Belarus

**Note:** This puzzle was inspired by [Which country is INDIA in?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30607/which-country-is-india-in)

However, I noticed that the question is not possible anymore with India.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is:

> Switzerland

Because:

> [Campione d'Italia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campione_d%27Italia) is an Italian exclave which is an enclave in Switzerland
>  [Baarle-Hertog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baarle-Nassau) is a Belgian exclave which is an enclave in the Netherlands
>  [Büsingen am Hochrhein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCsingen_am_Hochrhein) is a German exclave which is an enclave in Switzerland
>  [Nahwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahwa) is an exclave of the United Arab Emirates which is an enclave in Oman
>  [San'kovo-Medvezh'e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankovo-Medvezhye) is a Russian exclave which is an enclave in Belarus

Here's more:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_enclaves_and_exclaves

Comment: I was going to point out that India would be possible with this answer, but it turns out it isn't for a little less than a year! (about time they took care of that...)

Comment: @ffao Actually, there is still *one* enclave of Bangladesh in India (though not dozens like before).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> Switzerland

How?

> They are sharing their borders
>  
>  [Belgium is in The Netherlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgium%E2%80%93Netherlands_relations)
>
>  [Germany is in Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germany%E2%80%93Switzerland_relations)
>
>  [The UAE is in Oman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oman%E2%80%93United_Arab_Emirates_relations)
>
>  [Russia is in Belarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarus%E2%80%93Russia_relations)
>
>  So the Italia aka [Italy is in Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italy%E2%80%93Switzerland_relations)

Comment: And why Switzerland?  Could France, Austria or Slovenia not also be valid?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> Austria or Switzerland

Because;

> **Over** Belgium there is The Netherlands
>  **Below** Germany is Switzerland
>  **Right** to UAE is Oman
>  **Left** to Russia is Belarus
>  and back to **Over** Italy is **Austria or Switzerland**