# Japan is in India

Tags: lateral-thinking, geography, knowledge

Inspired by this question: [Which country is INDIA in?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30607/which-country-is-india-in)

Japan is in India.

New Caledonia is in Lima.

Greenland is in Quebec, but only during the winter.

Portugal is in November in the winter too.

Beijing is in the Hotel.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible because

> these are [military abbreviations for timezones.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones)

Comment: yup, that's it! too easy?

Comment: @Michael: Nah, I just work fast. First I saw that they were all NATO alphabet letters, then the "during the winter" thing made me think about what changed during the seasons - looked to see if timezones were referred to with letters and they were!